Validation error is being caught as a decoding error in Go Gin framework
I'm using the Gin framework in Go to bind and validate incoming JSON requests. However, I'm encountering an issue where validation errors are being caught as decoding errors. Specifically, when a validation error occurs, the error is being handled as a request body decoding failure instead of a validation failure.
Here’s my current code:
func checkPostReq(ctx *gin.Context, req any) (string, error) {
    if err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(req); err != nil {
        var validationErrs validator.ValidationErrors
        if errors.As(err, &validationErrs) {
            // Handle validation error
            err = apperror.WrapValidationErr(validationErrs)
        } else {
            // Handle decoding error
            err = apperror.ReqBodyDecodeFailed.Wrap(err, "failed to decode request body")
        }
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, apperror.ErrorResponse(ctx, err))
        return "", err
    }

    uidStr, err := checkUid(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, apperror.ErrorResponse(ctx, err))
        return "", err
    }

    return uidStr, nil
}


When I intentionally trigger a validation error, the error message looks like this:
ERROR "Key: 'CreatePostRequest.MainCategory' Error:Field validation for 'MainCategory' failed on the 'required' tag"

But instead of treating it as a validation error, it's being caught as a decoding error, and the ReqBodyDecodeFailed branch is executed.
Questions:
Why is the validation error being caught as a decoding error?
Is there a better way to differentiate between validation errors and decoding errors when using ShouldBindJSON?
How can I ensure that validation errors are handled correctly?
Thanks in advance!

My guess would be that the version of your validator package is different from the version that the gin/binding package uses.

Thank you for your suggestion! It turns out you were right.

the issue was caused by a version mismatch between the validator package used in my project and the one used by gin/binding. After updating the validator version to match, the problem was resolved.
